# How to prepare environment to run Tomcat server in the simplest way?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, tomcat

Is it possible to run my application, which uses MongoDB, Spring Framework etc. on other computer using one click like '.exe' applications ? 
I'd like to run my application in the most simplest way. I think that installing mongoDB (I don't want to use hosting) and Tomcat is required. Do I need something else ?

Answer (score 0):

Installing mongo is required but you don't have to install tomcat, you can instead embed it in your application with the help of Spring boot.